# How to display user's own uploaded data in react calendar timeline

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I am using this npm package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-calendar-timeline

I am trying to get data from json file and display it on the react calendar timeline, but I am unable to write code for that. Could anyone please help me display data on the timeline using axios or fetch method.
I am using generate-fake-data.js and faker component to display the fake data. I want the actual data named as event title and event description from my API (http://localhost:5000/events), to be loaded in the timeline.

This is what I want to show from my API using axios or fetch

This is result
[image]

This is what I want to show using axios or fetch
[image]

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the react app running on http:localhost:3000/

An easy way to achieve this would be in your package.json add:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"`

This will "proxy" all calls coming to http://localhost:3000 and will call http://localhost:5000 instead.

With this done, the next thing will be to actually make the call to your API in the react code.

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/events')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log("Events Data", data));
```

or

```
  axios.get('http://localhost:5000/events')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

Comment: Could you share some sample code and show what exactly it is that you're unable to do? 
I understood that you want to know how to make a fetch / axios call.

Answer (score 0):

Please have alook at my question again please. This is not something related to proxy settings. My question is about editing react-calendar-timeline and display my own data from my api on the timeline using axios or fetch method.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can display data from API responses by creating groups and items accordingly. After receiving the data we need to set new groups and items state and pass them to the Timeline component. Also, we can customize the groups and items as required by the groupRenderer method and itemRenderer respectively. Hope this will be helpful. Thank you.